# Forward user email address

Tags: 7, commerce, rules, webforms

I use Webform with Commerce product skus field. Now I have a rule to send out an email to customer if webform is submitted. That works fine. But I would like to set a rule to send the email when the customer check out. My problem is that i don't know the token which I have to set in this Drupal Commerce rule. In Webform rule, I use this [data:e_mail-value], but in the Drupal Commerce rule I have [commerce-order:mail] which is not the same, is it?

How can I forward the right user email address from webform submission to the final Drupal Commerce confirmation email?

Answer (score 0):

The "commerce-order:mail" token will only show the user email associated with whoever is logged in and submitting the order, while the webform email value from the token [data:e_mail-value] is a component in the webform submission and generally stores the submission with the author/owner being "anonymous".

- If your webform automatically redirects to the commerce cart/checkout, then I'd suggest forcing the user to be logged in before they even fill out the webform and hit submit. Then you can set the default value of the webform email field with a token for the email of current user and hide it from view.
- Otherwise, you'll need to write custom functionality to somehow store and pass the webform submitted data:e_mail-value to a hidden field associated with the order itself in the checkout process.

---

Also as a reminder for the "To" address field in the workflow rule for sending an email, you need to format it to comply with RFC 2822- by wrapping the email address string with <>.  For example:

[image: RFC 2822 compliant email address]

Should you want to send to multiple recipients, then you'll want a comma separated list of emails, each wrapped in <>.